# Pick out every word beginning with a capital letter

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach

I would like to pick out every word in a string which beggings with a capital letter, but an Array out of bounds error appears on line 3;

```
foreach (string strWord in words)
{
     if (Char.IsUpper(strWord[0]) && strWord.Length > 0)
     {
         Console.Write(strWord + " :: ");
     }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: _"Array out of bounds"_? Is it actually an "Index out of Bounds exception"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap the arguments, otherwise it crashes *before* checking:

```
if (strWord.Length > 0 && Char.IsUpper(strWord[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do the `strWord.Length > 0` first

```
if (strWord.Length > 0 && Char.IsUpper(strWord[0]))
{
     Console.Write(strWord + " :: ");
}
```

So you can make sure `strWord` has at least one letter before trying to get first letter.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that you are checking the value of strWord[0] first without first making sure that there is any letter in the word or not, so in-case the value of strWord is NULL the program throws an exception that the index 0 is being called though it has not been given value, so to rectify this problem you should check the length of the word first and then check if the character strWord[0] is Upper case or not this way if the string is NULL then if condition will be discarded before it gets to the second part corrected code 1:-

```
if (strWord.Length > 0)
{
    if(Char.IsUpper(strWord[0]))
    {
        Console.Write(strWord + " :: ");
    }
}
```

corrected code 2:-

```
if (strWord.Length > 0 && Char.IsUpper(strWord[0]))
{
    Console.Write(strWord + " :: ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the length check is first when you use the && operator because the arguments are evaluated in order. If the first argument fails the second will not execute, and the IsUpper is causing out-of-bounds errors when Length is 0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx

So you just need to swap the evaluations around:

```
if (strWord.Length > 0 && Char.IsUpper(strWord[0]))
{
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&&`-operator is a short-circuiting operator which mans that it only evaluates the first condition if that returns already `false`. So it's the right choice if you want to prevent an exception. But you have to use the correct order, first the check then the method that can fail.

So like this:

```
if (strWord.Length > 0 && Char.IsUpper(strWord[0]))
...
```

However, you could also use this neat LINQ query:

```
var allWordsThatStartWithUpperCaseLetters = words
    .Where(w => w.Length > 0 && Char.IsUpper(w[0]));
string result = string.Join(" :: ", allWordsThatStartWithUpperCaseLetters);
```